# making telegram bot that if user wants to send bot a massage he has to join a channel

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I want to make a telegram bot that people can send the bot a message if they first join a specific channel that the bot says

For example, if a user wants to send a message to the bot, the bot will tell the user that you have to join this channel then you can send me this massage

How can I write its code in python?

I've read related questions in this site but none of them answer my question clearly

thanks for your answers...

Answer (score 0):

If you add the bot to the channel as admin, you can use [`getChatMember`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchatmember) with the channel ID and the user ID.